# Smali moveTaskToBack

Tags: android, apk, smali

I just started in smali and I'm trying to add moveTaskToBack(true) in main activity (smali) but I don't know how to convert it.

Btw here's what I tried:

```
invoke-virtual {p0, v0}, Landroid/androapp/Main;->moveTaskToBack(Z)Z
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use apktool to decompile

```
java -jar apktool.jar d <file-to-decompile.apk>
```

Then edit the smali file where you want to insert the code.

But you have to make sure that at the point where you insert the code `v0` already contains the value `1` for true, or you have to set it to `1` but then make sure `v0` does not contain a value that is used later:

```
const/4 v0, 0x0
invoke-virtual {p0, v0}, Landroid/androapp/Main;->moveTaskToBack(Z)Z
```

Afterwards rebuild the app using apktool.

```
java -jar apktool.jar b <directory created by apktool>
```

If apktool succeeds you find the generated apk file in the `dist/` subdirectory.

Depending on the APK file that is modified you may have to align the apk using `zipalign 4 <modified apk file>` or `zipalign -p 4 <modified apk file>` (the latter has to be used in case the app defines `extractNativeLibs=false` in it's `AndroidManifest.xml`).

Now you have to resign the apk using e.g. `apksigner` for Android SDK.